# How to use Laravel's wildcards on route group before auth?

Tags: php, authentication, routes, laravel

I have this code below in my router.php

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() 
{
    Route::get('account/(:all?)', function() {});
    Route::get('facebook/(:all?)', function() {});
});

Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

It works well when the user is not logged in. But once he is successfully logged in and gets redirected to the requested page, the page is not displaying anything; just a blank page. I have tried to use :any instead of :all and it does the same thing.

Can anybody identify the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I did not find the better solution for using the group filter. The way I do it now to redirect guests to auth is this:

```
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    $open_routes = array(
        '', 
        'home', 
        'auth', 
        'help'
    );
    if(!in_array(URI::segment(1), $open_routes) && Auth::guest()) {
        return Redirect::to('/auth/login');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your routes are mapped to empty closures. You need to return something or map them to controllers.

```
Route::get('account/(:any?)', function() {
    return "Hello World";
});

Route::get('account/(:any?)', function() {
    return View::make('accounts.index');
});

//assuming you have an AccountController.php
Route::get('account/(:any?)', 'account@index');

//automatically route all methods of a controller
Route::controller('account');
```

Check out [the laravel docs on routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing).

Comment: have you tried returning text from the route like i did in the first example?